# Detecting keyboard errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, event-listener, beep

I am writing a script that requires the user to press multiple keys simultaneously. I keep track of which are pressed using onkeydown and onkeyup event listeners. However, certain combinations of keys are incompatible, usually resulting in a beep, and the event listener is not triggered. Is there any way to detect keyboard error?

Here is some of my code. If, for example, the user presses the following sequence without releasing, the computer will give an error beep: T,R,O. The 'O' will not trigger the keyDonwFn, though.

In the html code, I have onkeydown="keyDownFn(event);"

```
function keyDownFn(e) {
    if ( isCorrectKey( e.keyCode ) ){
        do A
    }else if (e.keyCode != currentKey){
        do B
    }else if (e.keyCode == currentKey){
        do C
    }
}
```

and I would like to have another else if for errors:

```
else if (e.keyCode == error){
    do D
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a relevant snippet of your code and an example of input that causes the problem.

Comment: Really improbable that the event listener is not triggered. You should assume it is your code unless you can prove otherwise. Show us what isn't working

Comment: As duskwuff discussed, most keyboards do not support n-key rollover. I'm just trying to detect when the keyboards limitations are reached. I edited to provide an example of a 3 letter combo that is incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this probably isn't possible.

Most of the limitations that you're describing are likely limitations of the keyboard hardware itself — most keyboards do not support [*n*-key rollover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)), so they are physically incapable of correctly detecting multiple keys being pressed at once. There is no notification at the hardware level that this is occurring, so it cannot be propagated to a web page.

It's also possible that some of the key combinations you're using are mapped to commands in the browser which cannot be captured by web pages. Again, if this is occurring, the event is not being propagated to the web page, so you cannot detect it.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no notification at the software level? There is an error beep, at least on my computer, when incompatible keys are hit simultaneously. Isn't that a hardware level notification?